# Branch.io deferred deep link missing data after install

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I'm trying to get deferred deep links working on Android. I added a test device in the dashboard & reset the device data and made sure the app is uninstalled. When I click a branch.io link, it takes me to the play store as expected. I then launch the app from Android Studio onto the phone, then the logs say that Branch SDK sent a request to `https://api2.branch.io/v1/install`, but the problem is the response doesn't contain the original link, query params, or key value pairs I set in the dashboard. This is the JSONObject I'm receiving in `onInitFinished`:

```
{"+match_guaranteed":true,"link_click_id":"976953359423305632","+clicked_branch_link":true,"+click_timestamp":1634196720,"+is_first_session":true,"utm_source":"test-referrer"}
```

**Where is all the other information? This doesn't include the original link, the key-value pairs, tags, etc.**

For a comparison, this is what I receive in the iOS app:

```
["$ios_passive_deepview": "branch_passive_default", "source": "test-referrer", "+is_first_session": 1, "~channel": test-referrer, "$matching_ttl_s": 7200, "~id": 976763609660742721, "~creation_source": 1, "$one_time_use": 0, "~marketing": 1, "~referring_link": "https://myapp.test-app.link/test-referrer", "~feature": "test", "+click_timestamp": 1634249299, "+match_guaranteed": 0, "$og_description": "My app description", "$og_title": "MyApp", "+clicked_branch_link": 1, "$marketing_title": "Test Referral Link", "~tags": ["test-referrer"], "~campaign": "test"]
```

If I rotate the phone to recreate the Activity or reopen the app a single time, it then sends a request to `https://api2.branch.io/v1/open` and returns all the info I expected initially. **How do I get the information after installing the app?**

I'm currently testing with myapp.test-app.link, and I call `Branch.enableTestMode()` before `Branch.getAutoInstance(this)` in my custom Application class's `onCreate()`. I also tried with a live link and got the same result.

These are the libraries I'm using in build.grade:

```
implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:5.0.13'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
```

I've also set up app links and the uri scheme in the dashboard as well as in the app. Using `getFirstReferringParams()` and `getLatestReferringParams()` on the first session after installing doesn't help either.

**UPDATE:**
Repeating the exact same testing process I described above, now the JSONObject that gets passed into `onInitFinished` has even less information and is claiming that I'm not clicking a branch link:

```
{"+clicked_branch_link":false,"+is_first_session":true}
```

And `getFirstReferringParams()` returns an empty json object.
I'm about to start looking for an alternative at this rate.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by adding `intent.putExtra("branch_force_new_session", true);` right after `this.activity.setIntent(intent);` when initialising the intent. Something like this:

```
...
this.activity.setIntent(intent);
intent.putExtra("branch_force_new_session", true);
Branch
  .sessionBuilder(this.activity)
  .withCallback(branchReferralInitListener)
  .reInit();
...
```

Look [here](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-full-reference#deeplink-via-push-notification) for the `branch_force_new_session` reference.

The other reason for the missing data is the non-existent link alias, but it looks like it is not the case as soon as you tried with the same link in iOS.

Here is a script example to apply the patch for the Flutter project (do it after every `pub get` or `pub update`). Modify the paths to use with an Android project built with any other framework:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# NOTE: You can have PUB_CACHE in a different location
PUB_CACHE="$HOME/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev"


getVersion() {
    echo "$packages" | grep "^$1 " | awk '{print $2}'
}

patchPackage() {
    flag=$1
    package=$2
    file=$3
    from=$4
    to=$5

    version=$(getVersion $package)
    sed -i'.bak' "$flag" "s/$from/$to/g" "$PUB_CACHE/$package-$version/$file"
    echo "✔️  $package $version"
}

# * flutter_branch_sdk
patchPackage -e flutter_branch_sdk 'android/src/main/java/br/com/rsmarques/flutter_branch_sdk/FlutterBranchSdkPlugin.java' 'this.activity.setIntent(intent);' 'this.activity.setIntent(intent);intent.putExtra("branch_force_new_session", true);'
```

Here is the link getter example in Flutter, I guess Java/Kotlin implementation would be similar:

```dart
StreamSubscription? _branchListener;
final Map<String, DateTime> _processedLinks = {};

/// Use [hot] set to `False` to start listening to deeplinks on a cold app launch
/// and to `True` to continue listening after returning to the app from the background.
Future<void> listenToAppLinks({bool hot = false}) async {
  if (!hot) {
    try {
      final InstallationAppReferrer installer = await InstallReferrer.referrer;
      if ([
        InstallationAppReferrer.iosDebug,
        InstallationAppReferrer.iosTestFlight,
      ].contains(installer)) {
        await reportAnalyticsProperties({'tester': true});
      }
    } catch (_) {}
  }

  if (hot) {
    await _branchListener?.cancel();
    _branchListener = null;
  }
  // You can also want to use FlutterBranchSdk.checkPasteboardOnInstall() here
  _branchListener = FlutterBranchSdk.initSession().listen(
    (data) => _processBranchEvent(
      data,
      calledFrom: 'listener',
      firstLaunch: store.state.data.firstTimeLaunch,
    ),
    cancelOnError: false,
    onError: (dynamic e) async {},
  );
  if (!hot && store.state.data.firstTimeLaunch) {
    _processBranchEvent(
      await FlutterBranchSdk.getFirstReferringParams(),
      calledFrom: 'getFirstReferringParams',
      firstLaunch: true,
    );
  }
  Future.delayed(
    const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    () async => _processBranchEvent(
      await FlutterBranchSdk.getLatestReferringParams(),
      calledFrom: 'getLatestReferringParams',
      firstLaunch: store.state.data.firstTimeLaunch,
    ),
  );
}

void _processBranchEvent(
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> data, {
  String calledFrom = 'listener',
  bool firstLaunch = false,
}) {
  String? link =
      data['~referring_link'] as String? ?? data['+non_branch_link'] as String?;
  if (link == null) return;

  final keyOnlyParams = data.keys.where(
    (key) =>
        data[key] == null ||
        data[key] is String && (data[key] as String).isEmpty,
  );
  if (keyOnlyParams.isNotEmpty) {
    final parts = link.split('?');
    link =
        '''${parts[0]}?${keyOnlyParams.join('&')}${parts.length > 1 ? '&${parts.slice(1).join('')}' : ''}''';
  }
  processUniLink(
    Uri.parse(link),
    campaign: data['~campaign'] as String?,
    firstLaunch: firstLaunch,
    medium: data['~feature'] as String?,
    source: data['~channel'] as String?,
    tags: List<String>.from(castOr<Iterable>(data['~tags'], [])),
  );
}

Future<void> processUniLink(
  Uri uri, {
  String? bankCode,
  String? campaign,
  bool firstLaunch = false,
  bool launch = false,
  String? medium,
  String? source,
  List<String> tags = const [],
}) async {
  final now = DateTime.now();

  /// Query params - https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually
  final String? linkStr =
      !uri.host.contains('-alternate') ? uri.queryParameters['link'] : null;
  final Uri link = linkStr != null ? Uri.parse(linkStr) : uri;

  /// Ignore unsupported links
  if (!link.toString().startsWith(RegExp('http|$appSchema'))) return;

  /// Ignore same links called twice within 15 seconds
  final DateTime? previousCallAt = _processedLinks[link.toString()];
  if (previousCallAt?.isAfter(now - 15.seconds) ?? false) return;

  _processedLinks[link.toString()] = now;

  ...
}
```

*EDIT (2024-01-18): Added a patch script and Flutter code examples.*

Comment: After a few days I just threw my hands up and switched to firebase dynamic links. But since you're the only one that's answered go ahead and have the bounty lol (It's been a week and even branch.io support hasn't gotten back to me about this.)

Comment: Thanks for the bounty!
While branch.io is not a cake and is buggy firebase links are not better in my experience and are even less flexible and less transparent.

Comment: @AlexandrPriezzhev I'm having the same issue. The deep link data is passed to me when the app is installed, but when it's not installed, it doesn't. The device goes to the Play Store for installation, and when it opens the app it doesn't redirect the user to the right screen. Is the only possible way to solve this implementing the Branch SDK?

Comment: @FabioR, when I met this issue nothing else worked for me. However I never had the issue again since I applied this solution (I have a script to add the line automatically on every `pub get`).

Comment: Thank you for such a fast reply @AlexandrPriezzhev! I opened a ticket in Branch.io, and they replied and now I'm waiting for their evaluation of my setup. I will try your solution, thank you!

Comment: @AlexandrPriezzhev that still didn't work for me. May I ask what you added to the $android_deep_link parameter when creating the link? I added the content that I have in my Firebase link, inside the "link" param, like "https://mywebsite.org/path". Is that how you did it?

Comment: @FabioR, this parameter (I think it should be named `$android_deeplink_path`) is not manually filled at all (defaults are used). We get the raw link (with all three `FlutterBranchSdk.initSession().listen()`, `FlutterBranchSdk.getFirstReferringParams()` and `FlutterBranchSdk.getLatestReferringParams()`) then ensure it was not processed yet and then parse it. The shape of a link collected can be different dependingly on the source.

Comment: @FabioR Probably it will help - in the Branch configuration "Enable App Links" should be enabled and correct SHA256 Cert Fingerprints provided. After that it works both with universal (HTTPS) links and your custom Android URI scheme.
"URI Scheme Deep Link Mode" is set to "Intelligent" and "March type" to "Normal".

Comment: I have just added a path example to automate the task

Comment: @FabioR I have added a Flutter code example.